# Dynamic MySQL Update Statement

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to write a prodecure that updates a value in a given column-name where the users id equals given user ID.

_strong_1 is a variable that contains the column name, i.e: 'category_1', for example.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C 
WHERE table_name = 'subscribers_preferences' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE _strong_1 INTO @columns;

SET @table = 'subscribers_preferences';
SET @s = CONCAT('UPDATE ',@table,' SET ', @columns = 1);

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

There's an error within the 'SET @s =' statement.  I can get it to work with a simple SELECT statement, but UPDATE is being tricky.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many columns are being listed in `@columns`?  If you have more than one, then you need to add the `=1` at the end of each column.  Otherwise you have `column1, column2 = 1` which isn't correct syntax, it should be `column1 = 1, column2 = 1`.

Comment: Is the `@columns = 1` statement right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `= 1` in quotes.

```
SET @s = CONCAT('UPDATE ',@table,' SET ', @columns, ' = 1');
```

Otherwise, you're comparing `@columns` with `1`, and concatenating either `1` or `0` (probably always `0`, since I doubt you have a column named `1`) to the SQL, which is creating invalid SQL.

Note that the above code will only update one column. If `@columns` is supposed to hold 3 columns, you need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` in your query that sets it.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(column_name, ' = 1')) AS @columns
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'subscribers_preferences' and column_name LIKE _strong_1;
SET @table = 'subscribers_preferences';
SET @s = CONCAT('UPDATE ',@table,' SET ', @columns);
```

I suspect you also need to add a `WHERE` clause to this SQL so it just updates the row for the given ID. As currently written, it will update all rows.

The fact that you need to write the query like this suggests improper normallization of your data. Instead of having each preference option in a different column, they should be different rows of the table, with the key being something like `(user_id, setting_name)`.

Comment: Well I'm looking for a solution to update 3 specific category columns out of 20 individual category columns.  The only other way I could do this is to create a category column, but this would result in users having 20 up to rows of data PER user... maybe thats the solution but it doesnt seem efficient

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it with 3 columns matching the pattern.

Comment: It's efficient if you have proper indexes. Any time you find yourself writing dynamic SQL, you should strongly consider that something is wrong with your design. You should generally be searching fields in your data, not metadata.

Comment: I think I will do the 20 rows variant, its more simple, and theres more data, but it's simpler and massive dumps do not occur, so i think it will be ok, thank you for your input.